# GORM : Always return empty results, even if records exists

Tags: mysql, go, orm, go-gorm

I used [GORM](https://gorm.io/).

I tried to follow example on docs.

I Have a table in MySQL DB called "Attachements"

Here is how i tried to get all records:

```
    type Attachements struct {
        reference int
        status int
        statusDate Timestamp
        path string
    }

func main() {

    db, err := gorm.Open(
        "mysql", 
        "root:passord@(localhost)/dwg_transformer?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local"
    )

    if err!=nil {
        panic("Cannot connect to DB")
    }

    db.DB()
    db.DB().Ping()
    defer db.Close()

    atts := []Attachements{}

    db.Find(&atts)
    fmt.Println(atts)

}
```

I also tried :

```
    rows, err := db.Model(&Attachements{}).Rows()
    defer rows.Close()

    if err != nil {
       panic(err)
    }

    att := Attachements{}

    for rows.Next() {
       db.ScanRows(rows, &att)
       fmt.Println(att)
    }
```

I also tried to query by column in this way :

```
    db.Where(&Attachements{status: 0}).Find(&atts)

    for _, v := range atts {
    fmt.Println("reference : ", v.reference)
    fmt.Println("path : ", v.path)
    }
```

But in all this case I got empty output (no print, no panic, no errors !)

I tried to retrieve a list of all tables in this way :

```
    tables := []string{}
    db.Select(&tables, "SHOW TABLES")
    fmt.Println(tables)
```

it ouputs me : `[]`

But when i check if "Attachements" table exists, it returns me `true` :

```
    check:= db.HasTable("Attachements")
    fmt.Println(check)
```

I can't understand what I missed (If so)...
Any ideas ?

Thank you so much in advance to any GO dev wo could face what's the problem here...

[Here is a screenshot of MySQL WorkBench : We can see the Attachements table and the rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpEU0.png)

**UPDATE (03/03/20 19:00):**

I tried to export all the fileds as suggested in comments like this :

```
type Attachements struct {
    Reference int
    Status int
    StatusDate Timestamp
    Path string

   }
```

The results are the same : no errors for all tests, and empty outputs.

**UPDATE (03/03/20 20:00):**

I added a `db.GetErrors()`, because as suggested in comments, GORM does not reports errors automatically :

`[2020-03-03 19:58:05]  Error 1146: Table 'dwg_transformer.attachements' doesn't exist`

Why my tables got a lowercase name?

Comment: I tried..same results (no outputs, nor errors)

Comment: Thanks @icza for your comments. I updated the post. `db.Find(&att)` does not return any errors but empty slice `[]` actually

Comment: Actually with gorm, you have to call `db.GetErrors()`, it doesn't return errors as they happen. Please do check that at the end.

Comment: Thats an important point : when i run `db.GetErrors()` i got `[2020-03-03 19:58:05]  Error 1146: Table 'dwg_transformer.attachements' doesn't exist `

Comment: Then go ahead and create it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last error indicates the table doesn't exist.

Quoting from [GORM: Conventions: Pluralized Table Name:](https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#Pluralized-Table-Name)

> Table name is the pluralized version of struct name.
>
> ```
> type User struct {} // default table name is `users`
>
> // Set User's table name to be `profiles`
> func (User) TableName() string {
>   return "profiles"
> }
> ```

So GORM will use a default table name `attachements` for your `Attachements` struct. Either change the table name in your database to this, or provide a `TableName()` method in which you return `"Attachements"`, e.g.:

```
func (Attachements) TableName() string {
   return "Attachements"
}
```